# Why can't I access a variable from another class Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run hello printer I get this error

> AttributeError: type object 'Setup' has no attribute 'hello'

please help!

hello printer

```
from rpg import *
print Setup.hello
```

rpg

```
class Setup(object):
   def setup(self):
       hello = 5
```

Comment: If you want a static variable form a class Alex answer is right but if u want a class attribute mine is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make `setup` method static or insert `self` argument.

```
class Setup(object):
    @staticmethod
    def setup():
        hello = 5
        print hello
Setup.setup()
```

As its a static method, you don't have to initialize a class.
or

```
class Setup(object):
    def setup(self):
        hello = 5
        print hello
s = Setup()
s.setup()
```

In this case you will have to create an object of `Setup` class as you will be accessing the class method.

Answer (score 0):

You define `hello` in the function `setup` so it does not belong to the class namespace. To access a class variable you need to define it in the class, not in a function:

```
class Setup(object):
    hello = 5
```

Comment: Wrong Answer, hello is static member now. how about class attributes?

Comment: How is this wrong? This is exactly what OP needs to do to make it work.

Comment: @Wombatz this is static variable but question is access to class members , this is why answer is wrong

Comment: Where did OP state that he wants a "class member"?

Comment: @Wombatz and he didnt say static memebr too

Comment: Of course not. But the absence of a preference does not make a certain solution wrong.