# Can't access variable from another class?

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
class A():
   def __init__(self):
       self.say_hello = "hello"

   def doneA(self):
       print "A done"

class B(A):
   def __init__(self):
       print self.say_hello

   def doneB(self):
       print "B done"

a = A()
b = B()

a.doneA()
b.doneB()
```

When I run it I get the error AttributeError: B instance has no attribute 'say_hello'

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653446/why-cant-i-access-a-variable-from-another-class-python/34653628#34653628

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a call to `super` in the constructor of class B, otherwise `say_hello` is never created. Like this:

```
class B(A):
   def __init__(self):
       super(B, self).__init__()
       print self.say_hello

   def doneB(self):
       print "B done"
```

If you're doing this in Python 2 (which you apparently are based on your print statements), you'll have to make sure that you're using a ["new style" class](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass) instead of an old-style class. You do this by having your `A` class inherit from `object`, like so:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.say_hello = "hello"

    def doneA(self):
        print "A done"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print self.say_hello

    def doneB(self):
        print "B done"

a = A()
b = B()

a.doneA()
b.doneB()
```

Running this script gives:

```
hello
A done
B done
```

Comment: See also [Super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: I tried this but i got TypeError: must be type, not classobj

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect usage in Python 2. Try it again.